# Stacked bar plots with scaled colors ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I am trying to generate a stacked bar plot using ggplot2.

Here is my toy data set.

```
toy.df <- data.frame(Sample=1:8, 
                cluster=c(rep("A1", 2), rep("A2", 2), rep("A3", 2), rep("A4", 2)),
                num = c(100, 300, 200, 250, 250, 240, 120, 100),
                Category = c(" hypo.","others", "hypo.", "others", "hypo.", "others", "hypo.", "others"),
                Color=c(rep("orange", 2), rep("green", 2), rep("blue", 2), rep("purple", 2)))
```

I nee a bar plot where the x axis correspond to "cluster" and y axis correspond to column "num" and the stacked bars correspond to category (others, hypo). I like to use the colors that are set in the table however I need a lighter (scaled) color for "hypo." group.

Do you have any idea how I can plot this using ggplot.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick and easy approach to achieve your desired result would be to use a manual scale based on the colors in your data, map `cluster` on `fill` and `Category` on `alpha` to add some transparency for the `"hypo."` category.

Note: The first `"hypo."` contains a leading space so we actually have three different categories. For this reason I used `trimws()` to remove get rid of this leading space.

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  Sample = 1:8,
  cluster = c(rep("A1", 2), rep("A2", 2), rep("A3", 2), rep("A4", 2)),
  num = c(100, 300, 200, 250, 250, 240, 120, 100),
  Category = c(" hypo.", "others", "hypo.", "others", "hypo.", "others", "hypo.", "others"),
  Color = c(rep("orange", 2), rep("green", 2), rep("blue", 2), rep("purple", 2))
)

library(tidyverse)

dat$Category <- trimws(dat$Category)

pal_fill <- dplyr::distinct(dat, cluster, Color) |>
  tibble::deframe()

ggplot(dat, aes(cluster, num)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = cluster, alpha = Category),
    position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = num, group = Category),
    position = position_stack(vjust = .5, reverse = TRUE), show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal_fill) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(.4, 1)) +
  guides(fill = "none", alpha = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]

As second option would be to use "true" lighter colors instead of transparent colors which however requires slightly more effort. For this approach you could map the interaction of `cluster` and `Category` on `fill` and lighten the colors used for `"hypo."` using e.g. `colorspace::lighten`. Additionally, to get a legend showing `Category` requires a hack, i.e. I add a fake `alpha` legend which I manipulate via the `override.aes` argument of `guide_legend`:

```r
pal_fill <- dplyr::distinct(dat, cluster, Category, Color) |>
  mutate(Color = if_else(grepl("^hypo", Category), colorspace::lighten(Color, .4), Color)) |>
  tidyr::unite(name, cluster, Category, sep = ".") |>
  tibble::deframe()

ggplot(dat, aes(cluster, num)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = paste(cluster, Category, sep = "."), alpha = Category),
    position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = num, group = Category),
    position = position_stack(vjust = .5, reverse = TRUE), show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal_fill) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1, 1)) +
  guides(
    fill = "none",
    alpha = guide_legend(
      reverse = TRUE,
      override.aes = list(fill = colorspace::lighten("grey40", c(0, .4)))
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please add the text (num)to the bar plots. Cause when I do so the number of hypo and others are switched.

Comment: Also when I run your first script I get this error. "Error in `palette()`:
! Insufficient values in manual scale. 3 needed but only 2 provided.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred."

Comment: See my edit. The reason for the error was that one of the "hypo."s contained a leading space (i.e. we had 3 different categories) )which I silently dropped in my first answer. In the edit I removed it explicitly using `trimws()`.

Comment: Thank you so much this is working now. I was wondering if there is a way so that I can plot the lighter shades(hypo) and then the darker shade(others) on top of it.

Comment: Sure. As is the easiest approach would be to reverse the order of the stack using `position_stack(reverse =) TRUE, ...)` in both `geom_col` and `geom_text`. Personally I would also reverse the order of the categories in the legend which I did via `reverse=TRUE` in `guide_legend`.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Stefan's example, one often forgets that colors can be modified with the *function* `scales::alpha`. Having done that, you could then use an identity aesthetic. It's then a bit tricky to get a legend, at least one like Stefan has in their nice answer - but you haven't explicitly asked for the legend ;)

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  mutate(newcolor = ifelse(grepl("hypo", Category), alpha(Color, .2), Color)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(cluster, num)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = I(newcolor)),
    position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = num, group = Category),
    position = position_stack(vjust = .5, reverse = TRUE)
  )
```

[image]

If you want to go down this way, *and* want a legend, you could force ggplot for example by using an "invisible" color aesthetic.

```r
dat %>%
  mutate( ## for this you will need to remove the whitespace 
    Category = stringr::str_trim(Category),
    newcolor = ifelse(grepl("hypo", Category), alpha(Color, .2), Color)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(cluster, num)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = I(newcolor), color = Category),
    position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE),
    ##remove the border 
    linewidth = 0
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = num, group = Category),
    position = position_stack(vjust = .5, reverse = TRUE)
  ) +
  ## change the legend fill manually 
  guides(
    color = guide_legend(
      reverse = TRUE,
      override.aes = list(fill = c("grey25", alpha("grey25", .2)))
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Haha. I know about `alpha()`. :D Actually played around with it myself before going the `alpha` approach.

Comment: @stefan I have never had a doubt that you knew alpha :) I just thought it's a great opportunity to remind of this sometimes really useful function

Comment: Yeah. It is. `alpha()` is quite handy from time to time.